# Hosting TFS on the Same IIS Site as SharePoint Server 2016

Tags: iis, web, sharepoint, tfs

I'm trying to figure out how to host Team Foundation Server 2015 on the same IIS site as my SharePoint Server 2016. Currently, the SharePoint IIS site hosts my main SharePoint web application and a few other custom applications I've developed separate from SharePoint.

I want to use the same address and port for all of my applications (SharePoint, TFS, and custom) without using host headers. That is, http://www.example.com/sharepoint, http://www.example.com/custom, http://www.example.com/tfs.

I've managed to install TFS and move the `/tfs` IIS application it creates over to the SharePoint IIS site by modifying the applicationHost.config and changing some other settings. I'm prompted to login when I browse to http://www.example.com/tfs, but after I login I just get a blank page.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: If you just mean want to use same port such as 8080 for TFS and SharePoint on the same server, this blog may help you:https://elhajj.wordpress.com/tag/install-tfs-2012-on-windows-server-2012-with-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Patrick, the article looks like it just describes the advanced installation process for TFS. I've gone through that process and moved the IIS virtual directory over to my existing IIS site manually.

Is it possible for TFS to work if it is moved to another IIS site with existing services and applications like SharePoint?